# pgloader: Socket error in "connect": EINTR (Interrupted system call) and HEAP-EXHAUSTED-ERROR

Tags: pgloader, eintr

These days, I try to migrate data from mysql to postgres using pgloader. I encountered `HEAP-EXHAUSTED-ERROR` and `Socket error`.
For `HEAP-EXHAUSTED-ERROR`, I have tried to reduce the batch size and workers, but it didn't work.
For `EINTR (Interrupted system call)`, I am not sure the root cause.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to build pgloader using Clozure CL, and it seems to work. Maybe the CCL offers a better Garbage Collector. see [Heap exhausted](https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader/issues/327)
You can also try the docker image:

```
docker pull dimitri/pgloader:ccl.latest
```

This way works for both issues.